# Creating a .apk file from existing project

Tags: android, mobile

This may sound like a stupid question with a "duh" answer but I'm really new to this.

I have a HTML/JS project I created in Eclipse. Can such a project be exported as an Android application or .apk?

Or does a new Android project need to be created and programmed in Java for what I'm trying to achieve?

(I know about Phonegap and it is not suitable for my project as it doesn't have support for WebGL that I need)

Comment: The embedded browser (webview) in Android doesn't support WebGL so you would have to host it and create an app which would launch a browser that has WebGL support to your site.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I don't believe webview is a browser. Firefox has support for WebGL and I've tested on an android tablet and it works great

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries, tools which will pack your code into a webview. So with some work you can create multiplatform web implementation, and the build too, ofc ( apk, ipa )

Check the Google for more, but one is popular: Phonegap.

```
Google: "platform independent web based mobile" "framework" " solutions"
```

Comment: Clearly is writen "Check the Google for more"

Answer (score 0):

You can open your eclipse project by Dream Weaver and build it by phone gap .
the integration between phone gap and Dreamweaver support all versions of WebGL .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Eclipse (and for all the others who do), the .apk file of the latest compilation you did is always found in the /bin folder of your project

Comment: wouldn't the project need to be an android project?

Comment: Yes it would. Otherwise I don't see how you could debug and run your code to test it